# Чем перезаписать потенциально опасные поля в объекте

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как в javascript/nodejs перезаписывать/убирать опасные поля. Например: роль пользователя, пароль и т.д

Понимаю, что можно использовать delete и т.д, но хочется сделать красиво, например, с помощью https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv

Есть идеи? Например, что-бы роль в любом случаем была равна заданному значению, например, нулю.

Суть:

```
{
  secret: password,
  public: data
}
```

Должно стать:

```
{
 secret: ПЕРЕЗАПИСАНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ,
 public: data
}
```

или

```
{
 public: data
}
```

Comment: Приведите нынешний вид объекта и желаемый(примерно)

Comment: Блыо: {secret: password, public: data} Должно стать:  {secret: ПЕРЕЗАПИСАНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ, public: data} или  {public: data}

Comment: Желательно без костылей по типу delete или {}.secret =  ПЕРЕЗАПИСАНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос

Comment: `Object.assign`, `_.merge/mergeWith` тоже не катят?

Comment: Код в вопросе нужно выделять ` ` если он в одну строку, или ``` ```, если в несколько

Comment: Возможно вы имеете ввиду отправление и хранение пароля на клиенте в зашифрованном виде? Если это так, то вам подойдет [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)

Comment: Непонятно, что и в какую сторону должно работать. Опиши подробнее, что ты вообще делаешь.

Comment: От чего защищаемся-то? Без ответа на этот базовый вопрос все дальнейшие рассуждения бессмысленны

Answer (score 1):

Работая со структурированными данными, как правило мы подразумеваем объекты с определенным состоянием. Это могут быть объекты с заполненными данными либо пустые (не заполненные). Сам факт удаления свойства из объекта говорит о его поведении, тоесть объект изменился (мутировал).

Применение `delete` к объекту с данными, не наилучший способ предоставить данные скрыв некие его свойства, а скорее наихудший, потому как данный подход нарушает целостность данных. Один раз удалив свойство, теперь вы не можете обратиться к нему из других методов и в данном случае возникнет ошибка.

В ООП есть такой принцип как [инкапсуляция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). Данный подход как раз применяется для того чтобы посредством внедрения (инкапсулируя) новых методов предоставить конечный интерфейс, в котором при обращении к некоторым свойствам или методам внутреннее состояние объекта гарантированно не нарушится, потому как за его реализацию отвечаете вы и только ваш код, другие разработчики не должны влиять на внутренний механизм данного объекта.

Если вам необходимо подготовить некие данные исключив или добавив другие свойства объекта, это можно реализовать с помощью инкапсуляции таким образом:

```js
class User {
  // Скрытое поле
  #password;

  constructor(firstName, middleName, lastName, password) {
    // Инициализация
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.middleName = middleName;
    this.lastName = lastName;

    // Скрытые (приватные) свойства

    this.#password = password;
    this._password = password;

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'secret1', {
      value: this._password + '1'
    });

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'secret2', {
      get: () => this.#password + '2'
    });
  }

  // доступ к паролю (с помощью геттера)
  // свойство "только для чтения"
  get __password() {
    return this.#password;
  }

  // доступ к паролю (с помощью метода)
  // свойство "только для чтения"
  getPassword() {
    return this.#password;
  }

  // перезапись пароля
  setPassword(password) {
    return this.#password = password;
  }

  getFullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.middleName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }

  getShortName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }

  toString() {
    return '[' + this.constructor.name + '] ' + this.getFullName();
  }
}

const user = new User('Alexandr', 'Radionovich', 'Borodach', 'password');

console.log('user.password       =', user.password);
// undefined

console.log('user.__password     =', user.__password);
// password

console.log('user.secret1        =', user.secret1);
// password1

// перезапись пароля
user.setPassword('rewrited');

console.log('user.getPassword()  =', user.getPassword());
// rewrited

console.log('user.secret2        =', user.secret2);
// rewrited2


// Дополнительные свойства демонстрирующие термин инкапсуляции

console.log('user.getShortName() =', user.getShortName());
// Alexandr Borodach

console.log('user.getFullName()  =', user.getFullName());
// Alexandr Radionovich Borodach

console.log('user.toString()     =', user.toString());
// [User] Alexandr Radionovich Borodach

console.log('`${user}`           =', `${user}`);
// [User] Alexandr Radionovich Borodach

console.log('user                =', user);

// User {
//   firstName: 'Alexandr',
//   middleName: 'Radionovich',
//   lastName: 'Borodach',
//   _password: 'password'
// }
```

Как видите при явном обращении к закрытым свойствам объекта `user` (`user.password` или `user.#password`) данные не будут выводиться. Если мы выведем содержание всего объекта через консоль `console.log(user)` мы также не обнаружим свойства `password` за исключением `_password`, а также мы не увидим там свойства `secret1` и `secret2`. Но при необходимости мы можем обратиться к данному свойству или влиять на его содержание через инкапсулированный механизм `user.getPassword()`, `user.setPassword()` и т.п.

Теперь давайте подробней рассмотрим каждый вариант в отдельности:

- Использование символа "_" `_password` - это старый дедовский метод сокрытия данных. Данный подход на самом деле не скрывает данные, а напоминает остальным разработчикам о том, что данное поле категорически не должно подвергаться мутации посредством внешнего влияния. Но на практике, ничто и никто не может гарантировать его целостность потому как данное свойство может подвергатся изменению под влиянием внешнего воздействия. Ответственность за целостность данных в данном случае ложится на всех разработчиков кто использует данный код.
  Тоесть среди разработчиков есть некая договоренность о том, что данное свойство является приватным и любое его изменение напрямую категорически запрещено.
- Использование символа "#" `#password` - это новый подход который к сожалению еще не на всех устройствах и браузерах поддерживается, но данный подход нужно учитывать и иметь в виду. Он действительно позволяет скрывать данные и не позволяет перезапись данных из внешнего воздействия. Ответственность целостности данных возлагается только на разработчиков поддерживающих данный код.
- [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) - данный метод позволяет добавить в ваш объект новое свойство и дать ему некие характеристики: скрытости и мутабельности (enumerable, writable, configurable), Подробнее смотрите в документации.

Давайте попробуем перезаписать наши данные и посмотрим что с ними произойдет:

```js
// на самом деле такого свойства нет в объекте user, в данном случае будет
// создано новое свойство со значением "new password"
user.password = 'new password';

// перезапись не произойдет, более того если вы используете 
// строгий режим ('use strict';) тогда возникнет ошибка, 
// свойство только для чтения
user.secret1 = 'new password';
user.secret2 = 'new password';
user.__password = 'new password';

// пароль успешно перезаписан
user._password = 'new password';
```

Также исключением некоторых свойств из объекта можно добиться еще одним более гуманным способом, это нововведенный [spread оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const user = {
  name: 'Dmitry',
  surname: 'Malinovsky',
  password: 'password'
};

const { password, ...userData } = user;

console.log(userData);
```

Еще один подход, именуемый как [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), который предложил пользователь [Voprositel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/358853/voprositel)

```js
let user = {
  name: "Вася",
  _password: "some_password"
};

function proxyPrivater(obj, key = '_') {
  obj = new Proxy(obj, {
    get(target, prop) {
      if (prop.startsWith(key)) {
        throw new Error("Отказано в доступе");
      } else {
        let value = target[prop];
        return (typeof value === 'function') ? value.bind(target) : value;
      }
    },
    set(target, prop, val) {
      if (prop.startsWith(key)) {
        throw new Error("Отказано в доступе");
      } else {
        target[prop] = val;
        return true;
      }
    },
    deleteProperty(target, prop) {
      if (prop.startsWith(key)) {
        throw new Error("Отказано в доступе");
      } else {
        delete target[prop];
        return true;
      }
    },
    ownKeys(target) {
      return Object.keys(target).filter(item => !item.startsWith(key));
    }
  });
  
  return obj;
}

user = proxyPrivater(user);

console.log(user._password)
user._password = 232;
delete user._password;
```

Comment: Ещё можно было упомянуть про защищенные свойства, те, что начинаются с `_`.

Comment: @Voprositel, ну и кто же их защищает?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что вопрос о десериализации недоверенных данных, в таком случае приватные поля, геттеры, сеттеры и методы вообще не в тему. Хотя изначально я подумал про фактическое затирание памяти, для которого они тоже не очень в тему.

Comment: @Qwertiy, [негласное соглашение](https://learn.javascript.ru/private-protected-properties-methods#zaschischyonnoe-svoystvo-wateramount))

Comment: @Voprositel, очевидно, что вопрос не про это. Впрочем, если вопрос действительно про десериализацию, то если назвать все опасные поля с `_`, то можно будет потом потереть все поля, начинающиеся с него. Хотя, для десериализации и другой мусор иметь не слишком-то и полезно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, понятно, что вопрос про другое, но почему бы и не добавить?

Comment: Использование lodash `_` - это старый дедовский метод, в котором защиты данных как таковой нет, это скорее напоминание сознательному разработчику что данное поле не должно использоваться внешним фактором. Лучше использовать современный механизм.

Comment: @AlexanderYukal, вы правы, но современный механизм не везде поддерживается, к тому же он не распространяется на методы

Comment: Может способ с `_` и дедовский, но его можно неплохо модернизировать с помощью Proxy - https://learn.javascript.ru/proxy#zaschischyonnye-svoystva-s-lovushkoy-deleteproperty-i-drugimi

Comment: @Voprositel Предложите свой вариант, я его рассмотрю и добавлю или добавьте новый ответ я его поддержу :)

Comment: @AlexanderYukal, [вот](https://codepen.io/kertaw/pen/BaLpNGB), способ с функцией. Добавьте его себе в ответ

Comment: Пожалуйста, пересмотрите мой способ, я его обновил. В ловушке `ownKeys(target)` я изменил строчку `return Object.keys(target).filter(key => !key.startsWith('_'));`, она была слегка неверной и также я добавил тестов